# WAV audio format: MPEG3 to PCM

Tags: wav, pcm

How can you convert wav files with MPeg layer 3 (MPeg3) audio format to PCM?

Comment: do you mean MPEG1 audio layer 3 aka mp3? MPEG3 doesn't exist.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org) called from the command-line, like so:

```
ffmpeg -i source.wav -f wav -acodec pcm dest.wav
```

**NOTE**: Untested

Also, Windows binaries are available (I had some from another place as well) [here](http://ffdshow.faireal.net/mirror/ffmpeg/).

Answer (score 2):

[LibMAD](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If finding a windows binary of ffmpeg is too much work you can install [foobar2k](http://www.foobar2000.org/) and do it from there